# Prolog - searching a list inside a predicate

Tags: list, prolog

I have predicates of students and sports they do, and I want to find out which students do a particular sport. I have this sofar, but i can only get results if I enter exact sports in a list , and my find predicate works only to find a sport in a list. I don't know how to put it together to use to find students that do 1 sport:

```
student('Quinton Tarentino', male, 12).
student('Tom Hanks', male, 9).
student('Ed Harris', male, 11).

does_sport('Quinton Tarentino', [soccer, hockey, cricket]).
does_sport('Tom Hanks', []).
does_sport('Ed Harris', [hockey, swimming]).

sports([soccer, hockey, swimming, cricket, netball]).

find(X) :- sports(L), member(X, L).
```

I tried things like:

```
?- does_sport(X, find(soccer, L)).
```

This just returns false. I know I need to link my sports list to the does_sports predicate but not sure how.

Any advice appreciated :)

Comment: It's Que̲ntin for sure.

Answer (score 3):

To *find out which students do a particular sport*, you could define a predicate like so:

```
student_sport(St,Sp) :-
   does_sport(St,L),      % L is a list of sports student St does
   member(Sp,L).          % Sp is a member of list L
```

Then you can query for e.g. soccer, as you seem to intend in your question, like so:

```
   ?- student_sport(St,soccer).
St = 'Quintin Tarentino' ? ;
no
```

Hockey on the other hand yields two results:

```
   ?- student_sport(St,hockey).
St = 'Quintin Tarentino' ? ;
St = 'Ed Harris' ? ;
no
```

If you want to have a list of students doing hockey instead, you can use `findall/3` like so:

```
   ?- findall(St,student_sport(St,hockey),L).
L = ['Quintin Tarentino','Ed Harris']
```

Or alternatively `setof/3` to get a sorted list (without duplicates, in case you happened to have facts that contain any):

```
   ?- setof(St,student_sport(St,hockey),L).
L = ['Ed Harris','Quintin Tarentino']
```

Note that in some Prologs you might have to explicitly include a library to use `member/2`, e.g. in Yap: `:- use_module(library(lists)).`, while others autoload it, e.g. SWI.

### EDIT:

Concerning the issues you raised in your comment, let's maybe start with your observation that `student_sport/2` produces the answers one at a time. That is intentional, as suggested by the predicate name that contains the word *student* in singular: It describes a relation between a student and a particular sport that very student practices. That's why I added the example queries with `findall/3` and `setof/3`, to show ways how you can collect solutions in a list. You can easily define a predicate `students_sport/2` that describes a relation between a particular sport and a list of all students who practice it:

```
students_sport(L,Sp) :-
   setof(St,student_sport(St,Sp),L).
```

Concerning the sports-austere, you can choose an atom to denote that case, say `none` and then add an according  rule to `student_sport/2` like so:

```
student_sport(St,none) :-   % <- rule for the sports-austere
   does_sport(St,[]).       % <- succeeds if the student does no sport
student_sport(St,Sp) :-
   does_sport(St,L),
   member(Sp,L).
```

This yields the following results:

```
   ?- student_sport(St,none).
St = 'Tom Hanks' ? ;
no

   ?- students_sport(St,none).
St = ['Tom Hanks']

   ?- students_sport(St,hockey).
St = ['Ed Harris','Quintin Tarentino']

   ?- students_sport(St,Sp).
Sp = cricket,
St = ['Quintin Tarentino'] ? ;
Sp = hockey,
St = ['Ed Harris','Quintin Tarentino'] ? ;
Sp = none,
St = ['Tom Hanks'] ? ;
Sp = soccer,
St = ['Quintin Tarentino'] ? ;
Sp = swimming,
St = ['Ed Harris']
```

And finally, concerning your assumption of your code being exactly as I wrote it: There is a similarity in structure, namely your predicate `find/1` having a first goal (`sports/1`) involving a list and subsequently using `member/2` to check for membership in that list. The second rule (or single rule before the edit) of `student_sport/2` is also having a first goal (but a different one: `does_sport/2`) involving a list and subsequently using `member/2` to check for membership in that list. Here the similarities end. The version I provided is not using `sports/1` at all but rather the list of sports associated with a particular student in `does_sport/2`. Note that `find/1` does not describe any connection to students whatsoever. Furthermore your query `?- does_sport(X, find(soccer, L)).` indicates that you seem to expect some sort of return value. You can regard predicates as functions returning `true` or `false` but that is usually not very helpful when programming Prolog. The argument `find(soccer,L)` is not being called as you seem to expect, but literally passed as an argument. And since your facts do not include something along the lines of

```
does_sport(*SomeStudentHere*, find(soccer,L)).
```

your query fails.

Comment: Thanks Tas, the findall and setof work 100% but student_sport(St, hockey). only returns only one student every time, even when I have more than one doing the sport, and I (think) my code is exactly as you wrote it here. Also  I'm not sure how to represent an empty list, for example 'Tom Hanks' does no sports. If I just pass blank or '' or [],  I simply get false.

Comment: @ildsarria: I updated my answer to address the issues you raised in your comment.